# Not able to retain the values of search if some action is performed on the search result

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, search

I have a page index.php, that has a list of data coming from the table like this

```
Name    Age  Location   Action
N1      A1      L1      Add
N2      A2      L2      Add
N3      A3      L3      Add
N4      A4      L4      Add
N5      A5      L5      Add
```

and the code responsible for the above output is

```
<div id="result">
    <?php foreach($data as $per_data): ?>
        <div> <php echo $per_data->name; ?> </div>
        <div> <php echo $per_data->age; ?> </div>
        <div> <php echo $per_data->location; ?> </div>
        <a href="<?php base_url(); ?>add/<?php echo $per_data->id; ?>">Add</a>
    <?php foreach;?>
</div>
```

This page also has a search bar that helps the user to perform a search on basis of age and location. The data of this search form is submitted through ajax like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#search_form").submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();  
var age = $("#age").val();
var location = $("#location").val();
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "search_result",
      data: { age:age, location:location },   
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data)
        $("#result").html(data); 
      }
  });
})
</script>
```

After the search, the view becomes something like this

```
Name    Age  Location   Action
N1      A1      L1      Add
N3      A3      L3      Add
N5      A5      L5      Add
```

As you can see the index page has a data and along with that it also has an "add" link, which performs some action. After the search, resulting data is displayed in the same format along with the "add" link. Now if I click on the add link, some action will be performed and that particular row will get affected, but here is the problematic area. After the link is clicked, the page gets reloaded and the div that was showing the data according to the search now is displaying the entire data that was there before the search.

I want that after the search is performed if the user clicks on the add link the row should get affected due to its action but the search result should remain the same.

So, if the search returns 3 rows and I click on any add link then after that also the same 3 rows should be displayed to the user

Comment: Add the search query as parameter in each of the 'add link' urls.

Comment: You can as well store search result in session.

Comment: show your full code,it is impossible to give you solution with SUDOKO

Comment: It's impossible even with that, for example title `Not able to preform search` then `Now if I click on the add link, some action will be performed and that particular row will get affected, but here is the problematic area. After the link is clicked, the page gets reloaded and the div that was showing the data according to the search now is displaying the entire data` In other words the search works, but because they are using a link it wipes the results, which is no surprise.  So basically they need that link to instead trigger some ajax, or they need some what to maintain state...

Comment: You should really consider how you word and describe your issue, because it should't take so much work to figure out what you want.  Which is to maintain state after clicking the `Add` link, but you know it's a link. And requests are stateless, so one expects to lose state on a new request.  This is why we have AJAX, this is not something that can just be "Answered" because it's poorly designed.  Not to say it's baddy designed, it's just designed in way that doesn't lend itself to maintaining the state of the search..